# Javascript yield is not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have this function,which I tested on `postman` and is working fine.

```
export const createAccount = (password,mnemonic) => {
  axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:4000/createAccount',{
    password,
    mnemonic
  })
    .then((res)=> {
      console.log('--------res', res);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log('--------err222', err);
    })
  
}
```

Here is how I want to use it in my generator function with yield

```
const mnemonic = yield call(createMnemonicFromPassword, action.payload);
  const seed = yield call(createAccount,action.payload,mnemonic);
  


  const newUser = {
    mnemonic,
    seed,
    password: action.payload,
    nonce: 0,
  };


  yield put(setUser(newUser));
```

Everything is working fine but when it comes to the `createAccount` functions it gives **me error code `500`** and I dont understand why because this route works perfectly on postman,and even when I just **console.log(createAccount(arg1,arg2))** it is giving me correct output

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What does this have to do with `yield`? And what are `call` and `put`, what framework are you using?

Comment: What is the error? Where does your server code fail? Fix this first. Then work out the difference between the axios and the postman requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return promise in `createAccount` function, if you are using sagas `call` effect. Also make sure you are returning response at the end of `then`:

```
export const createAccount = (password,mnemonic) => {
  return axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:4000/createAccount',{
    password,
    mnemonic
  })
    .then((res)=> {
      console.log('--------res', res);
      return res;
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log('--------err222', err);
    })
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but it still gave me same error even tho i just copy/pasted ur version

Comment: Turns out my mnemonic variable is undefined

Comment: Your solution solved the problem,i will be able to accept it in 2 mins

Comment: Glad it helped!